# Git initialize old project from local pc to remote server

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've an old project in the production. The code of this project is in my local pc without the images that uploaded in the server. Today I've extended the project with new features.

Now I want to use git with this project. I've initialize git in it. Then I have created a repository to my bitbucket account and I have pushed my project from my local pc.

The problem that I have is that I want to `clone` the project from bitbucket to my server keeping the images that there aren't in the bitbucket. How can I do that?

Could I copy only the .git file from local to my server and then I `pull` the project from bitbucket?

Comment: Where do the images live?

Comment: In the public/img folder of project root

Comment: I suppose the repository does not have a `public/img/` folder?

Comment: The folder  `public/img/` exist but ignored by git because I've added this to `.gitignore` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As always before trying something out: do a backup beforehand*

In case the folder `public/img/` does not exist in the repository (is not tracked) the case is quite easy.

- On your server go to the folder which should be the root of the repository
- Initialize an empty git repository in this folder

  ```
  $ git init
  Initialized empty Git repository in /some-directory/
  ```
- Add your bitbucket repository as a remote

  ```
  $ git remote add origin <url-to-bitbucket-git-repo>
  ```
- Fetch all your fresh changes

  ```
  $ git fetch origin
  ```
- Finally check out the branch you want (assuming **master**) and set up tracking

  ```
  $ git checkout --track origin/master
  ```
- It will not overwrite your `public/img/` folder if it does not exist in the repository

---

#### Handling old application files

Create a new branch to hold the *old* files

```
git checkout -b <old-application>
git add -v old-application-files/
git commit # Message should indicate that this is an older state of the application
```

Make sure not include the images folder into this commit (these commits)

Now the `git checkout master` should work and you can see what was changes between the *old* state and the current one by doing a [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

```
git diff <old-application> master
```

---

***Addition***: To get files into the **new application** that **only existed** in the **old application**

While on **master**

```
git checkout <old-application> -- ./
```

This will checkout all the files you committed as they were in the old application (see the last form of [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) for more information

```
git reset HEAD ./
```

This will **unstage** all those changes introduced by doing `git checkout` before

```
git checkout -- ./
```

This will override modified files with the files from **master**. Files not yet in **master** will stay as they were.

**Job done**

---

In the future simply go to this folder and do a `git pull`

Comment: After `git merge origin/master` I got error: `error: Untracked working tree file '.env.example' would be overwritten by merge.
fatal: read-tree failed`.

Comment: Try moving the `.env.example` file away (`mv -v .env.example .env.example.temp`). Doing the merge and then compare `.env.example.temp` with the now **repository provided** `.env.example`

Comment: I did it but that problem is in the whole project  `error: Untracked working tree file 'app/About.php' would be overwritten by merge.
fatal: read-tree failed`

Comment: I think the problem is when the project in the server Initialized by `git init` track all project files and there is that conflict

Comment: Do you want to keep the _old_ application files? Because those shouldn't be needed, right?

Comment: I want to keep only the files that there aren't  in the bitbucket repository. And the old files will be overwritten by bitbucket repositroy

Comment: I will edit in a moment to incorporate that last bit of information. Basically merging `old-application` into `master` while throwing away changes from `old-application`, but keeping files that are not existing on `master`. Does this sound correct?